# Synchronization of two method which work on ArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronization, runnable

I have **Sum** class, **Creator** class, **Item** class and **Main**. The **Creator** creates random Items and adds them to an ArrayList which is in the **Item** class. The **Sum** class reads items and sums the weight of all. In the **Main** class I start in multiple threads **Creator** and **Sum**. Both classes implement **Runnable** and override the run method. After 200 created are items into is printed in the console.

**How to synchronize this methods?** When I start threads, the method from Sum ends first and returns weight 0 and after that Creator creating 40 000 random Items. I will create items and at the same time Sum all weights of them and in the end Return how many items were created and weight of all of them.

**Sum class method:**

```
@Override
    public synchronized void run() {

        for(Towar x: Towar.list){
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            counter++;
            sum+=x.getWaga();
            if(counter%100==0){
                System.out.println("Sum of "+counter+" items");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total weight of Items: "+sum);
    }
```

**Creator class method:**

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        reader=new Scanner(text);
        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            counter++;
            String[] x=reader.nextLine().split("_");
            synchronized (Towar.getList()){
                Towar.add(new Towar(x[0], Integer.parseInt(x[1])));
                Towar.list.notify();
                if(counter%200==0){
                    System.out.println("Created "+counter+" items");
                }
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Created in total: "+counter+" items");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `BlockingQueue`

I would recommend using implementations of the [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) interface, instead of `ArrayList`. A `BlockingQueue` is [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

To quote the Javadoc:

> `BlockingQueue` implementations are thread-safe. All queuing methods achieve their effects atomically using internal locks or other forms of concurrency control. However, the bulk Collection operations `addAll`, `containsAll`, `retainAll` and `removeAll` are not necessarily performed atomically unless specified otherwise in an implementation. So it is possible, for example, for `addAll(c)` to fail (throwing an exception) after adding only some of the elements in `c`.

### Example code

```java
 class Producer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Producer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
        reader=new Scanner(text);
        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
            counter++;
            String[] x=reader.nextLine().split("_");
            q.put(new Towar(x[0], Integer.parseInt(x[1])));
            if(counter%200==0){
              System.out.println("Created "+counter+" items");
            }
        }
        q.put(null);
        System.out.println("Created in total: "+counter+" items");
   }
 }

 class Consumer implements Runnable {
   private final BlockingQueue queue;
   Consumer(BlockingQueue q) { queue = q; }
   public void run() {
     long sum = 0;
     try {
       while (true) { 
          Towar x = (Towar)queue.take();
          if (x == null) return;
          counter++;
          sum+=x.getWaga();
          if(counter%100==0){
                System.out.println("Sum of "+counter+" items");
          }
       }
     } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... handle ...}
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

**CountDownLatch**
You can do it in multiple ways. One way of doing it using CountDownLatch to wait on the number of items provided to be created and pass a Signal for Sum Thread saying creation is done.
List will throw Concurrent Modification while 1 thread is adding objects and another one is using Enhanced for loop. You can get away with this problem either by using a Simple for loop or while loop etc.

```
I have written a Sample Program that can be used for your requirement. Go thru it 

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class SynchronousListItems {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

        CountDownLatch creatorLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        CountDownLatch sumLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        int numberOfItemsToCreate = 100;

        Thread createrThread = new Thread(new Creator(items, creatorLatch, numberOfItemsToCreate));
        createrThread.setDaemon(true);

        Sum sumObj = new Sum(items, sumLatch);

        Thread sumThread = new Thread(sumObj);
        sumThread.setDaemon(true);

        createrThread.start();
        sumThread.start();

        try {
            creatorLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            sumObj.setStopSignal(true);
        }

        try {
            sumLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

class Creator implements Runnable {

    private List<Item> items;

    private CountDownLatch creatorLatch;

    private int numberOfItemsToCreate;

    public Creator(List<Item> items, CountDownLatch creatorLatch, int numberOfItemsToCreate) {
        this.items = items;
        this.creatorLatch = creatorLatch;
        this.numberOfItemsToCreate = numberOfItemsToCreate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Random random = new Random(10L);

        while (numberOfItemsToCreate > 0) {
            int wage = random.nextInt();
            System.out.println(wage);
            items.add(new Item(wage));
            numberOfItemsToCreate--;
        }

        creatorLatch.countDown();
    }

}

class Item {

    private int wage;

    public Item(int wage) {
        this.wage = wage;
    }

    public int getWage() {
        return wage;
    }

}

class Sum implements Runnable {
    private boolean stopSignal;

    private List<Item> items;

    private int total;

    private int itemsCounter;

    private CountDownLatch sumLatch;

    public Sum(List<Item> items, CountDownLatch sumLatch) {
        this.items = items;
        this.sumLatch = sumLatch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            while (!stopSignal) {
                if (items != null && !items.isEmpty() && items.size() > itemsCounter) {
                    System.out.println("Itemes are not empty");
                    System.out.println("Itemes Counter " + itemsCounter);
                    while (itemsCounter < items.size()) {
                        Item item = items.get(itemsCounter);
                        System.out.println("Item Pulled");
                        total = total + item.getWage();
                        itemsCounter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Final Items Counter :" + itemsCounter);
            System.out.println("Total :" + total);
            sumLatch.countDown();
        }
    }

    public void setStopSignal(boolean stopSignal) {
        this.stopSignal = stopSignal;
    }
}
```